# Setting active tab based on url

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I have a simple tabbed interface that switches between hidden div and sets an active state on the appropriate tab when clicked.

When someone visits the url of the tab, it shows the contents of that tab only, which is fine.

**What I need it to do is also set the active state of that tab if you visited that url directly.**

I've got url's such as abc.com/index.html#gallery, abc.com/index.html#recipes etc.

So if you visit abc.com/index.html#recipes - the recipes tab is highlighted.

My code is below, thanks in advance for any advice!

```
    $(function () {
var app = {
        vars: {
            gallery: $('#gallery'),
            tabContent: $('.tabs .tabContent'),
            nav: $('.tabs nav a')
        },
        events: function () {
            //tabs
            app.vars.nav.on('click', function (e) {
                var thisHash = $(this).attr('href');
                app.setHash(thisHash);
                e.preventDefault();
                $('nav a').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });

            //hashchange
            $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
                app.checkHash();
            });

        },
        checkHash: function () {
            var hash = app.getHash();

            if (hash == '') {
                app.vars.tabContent.hide();
                app.vars.gallery.show();
            } else {
                app.goTo(hash);
            }

        },
        getHash: function () {
            return window.location.hash;
        },
        setHash: function (id) {
            window.location.hash = id;
        },
        goTo: function (id) {
            app.vars.tabContent.hide();
            $(id).fadeIn();
        }
    }
app.events();
app.checkHash();


});
```

Comment: What problems do you have with your current code?

Comment: At the moment if I visit that page with the has at the end, it shows the correct content, but the wrong tab is highlighted. I need it to highlight the tab based on the url.

Answer (score 0):

You need to amend the `goTo` function to set the `active` class on the relevant tab. Try this:

```
goTo: function (id) {
    app.vars.tabContent.hide();
    $(id).fadeIn();
    $('nav a[href="' + id + '"]').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
}
```